# How to expand div in all direction after content loading?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a popup div `position:fixed`. initially i want to display a loading image, till the content is not loaded.

i used

```
 this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop()  + "px");

this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft()  + "px");
```

to center the div according to screen. It works fine.

Problem occurs after content is loaded, since the content ranges from **simple text paragraphs to complex forms**,they expand in **right and bottom** direction. Since my div was centered according to that small "loading" image, now with new content it is more towards right and bottom.

Is there any way by which i can expand the div in all 4 direction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's fix up your div centering.  For a fixed div, consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.center
            {
                position: relative;
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                background-color: red;
            }

            div.fix
            {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 100px auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="fix"><div class="center"></div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will center your div dynamically, no matter HOW it's sized, or how it changes (both height and width).  It's also very much not-hacky (which I approve of).  Try applying this sort of CSS to your issue and it should resize gorgeously.